# C# asp.net Maintain tab index after asynchronous postback ontextchanged

Tags: c#, textbox, postback, tabindex

Ok, so I've researched this to the end of the earth and can't seem to find a solution that works.

I have a C# application, which is basically a web form made up of radio button lists and text boxes in an update panel.  The form has multiple 'sections', each of which the user submits when completed.  Each control performs a postback.  This is because if the user modifies a section after completing it, the 'section saved' label needs to disappear.

This all works well, except the postbacks lose the tab order of the controls.  I have found code examples that save the last control that had focus, which works well for the radio button lists,  but because the text boxes post back when a user tabs to the next control (not modifies the text), it doesn't select the next control.  The user has to hit tab again and it jumps to the third text box, not the second because technically, the second text box is what had focus after the initial postback.  I hope this makes sense.

Any ideas?  I can post code if required.

I should probably also add that this page is within a frame of our community portal.